# Joining two tables by date range

Tags: mysql, date, join, left-join

I have two tables `org_years` and `year_days` structures of which are as follows :

[image: org_years table]

[image: year_days table]

I am looking to get a listing of all days for that organization and the org year id they belong to.

```
      org_years.id   |   for_date
-------------------------------------
      1              2016-01-01 
      1              2016-01-02 
      1              2016-01-03 
      1              2016-01-04 
      ..
      ..
      1              2016-12-31
      2              2017-01-01
      2              2017-01-02
```

the date ranges need not always be 1st jan to 31st dec. It's just an example.These can be date ranges during any time of the year.

Also date ranges will never overlap. Also PHP application logic will ensure that there will be no gaps in date ranges. A day will always lie in a date range.

Comment: You have a table that records that a year starts on the first day of the year and ends on the last day of the year. I'm dumbfounded.

Comment: updated my description :) these can be custom date ranges too

Comment: They need not be. But they always *are*

Answer (score 1):

Do a `LEFT JOIN` bewtween `year_days` and `org_years`, checking to see into whose annual range the `for_date` falls, for each record in `year_days`.  Note that I take into account the possibility that a day in your `org_years` calendar table might not fall into a range, in which case I display -1 as the `id`.

```
SELECT COALESCE(t2.id, -1) AS org_years_id,
       t1.for_date
FROM year_days t1
LEFT JOIN org_years t2
    ON t1.for_date BETWEEN t2.year_start_on AND t2.year_end_on
```

Comment: I will use application logic to ensure that a day always has to fall in a date range. Also, the date ranges need not always be 1st jan to 31st dec. These can be date ranges during any time of the year. I will run some this query and check it now :)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use below join condition

```
select t1.*,t2.* from Table1 t1 left join Table2 t2 ON 
DATE_FORMAT(t1.year_start_on,'Y') = t2.for_date
```